# What does input_components do in a Chrome extension manifest?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the [Chrome extensions documentation page for manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest), there is an undocumented setting called `input_components`. What does it do?

Comment: I opened a request for documentation https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/250

Answer (score 4):

`input_components` is part of the (terribly documented) [`chrome.input.ime` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime).

If you want to know how it works, see [this example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/input.ime/basic) and/or read [Chromium's source code](https://cs.chromium.org/file%3Aextensions%20input_components).